# Increase Page Viewer Web Part Zoomed View

Tags: content-editor-web-part, page-viewer-web-part

I  have a PDF file that's fairly small. I inserted the Page View Web Part and need to keep a view of 300% so other viewers don't have to increase the size to see the page. Is there scripting I could use in a Content Editor webpart to keep this size?